# Is there an event that fires when a binding is updated?

Tags: silverlight, events, data-binding

Is there an event that fires when a binding is updated?

For example, I'd like to create a behavior to be applied to a Combobox that does something every time the Combobox's ItemsSource is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution that I can think of is, when you say, you want to capture the itemsource change event. Normally this happens when you load the data or source data associated with change, I would raise a property changed event from the actual data source change and intercept that event and do what ever you need to do for item source change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NotifyOnSourceUpdated, use that event in the combobox

edit: oops didn't notice you're asking for silverlight, it exists in wpf :x

Answer (score 0):

The whole mechanism is practically based on the propertychanged event, so you can just use that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Notter Answered the question : to know if a Binding completed, use the TargetUpdated event of your control, and in the binding that interest you, put NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true